# GREE(Open feint) in ios - Update score not working in test account

Tags: ios, leaderboard, openfeint, gree

I'm testing with integration of GREE. The update score in leaderboard is not working in test account. Anyone if has been successful with GREE integration, please help. The score remains unchanged after calling submitwithblock method for the GREEScore object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Gree and they asked me to create New test application and new test user. This helped me fix the issue. Hope it may be helpful for someone in future.